# what is function Function implies in javascript?

Tags: javascript

opening chrome dev tools and check Function,

result comes out like

`ƒ Function() { [native code] }`

I cannot really understand this outcome because other articles refers that

> function is the language keyword that define functions
>
> Function is the built in prototype object that represents all
>   functions. And Function can be used as a constructor also using new
>   keyword

```
ƒ Function() { [native code] }
```

above seems like if Function is included in the function. (vice versa)

Can anyone help me to understand this issue?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman 
this is totally different question. I have already read the 'duplicated' article.

Comment: Reopened the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "above seems like if Function is included in the function. (vice versa)"... I'm confused

Comment: @maja
Function is an Object( built-in prototype object) so Object Function make sense. isn`t it..?
as f Function is same as function Function, it makes me so confused.
function is just the language keyword which defines function..

Comment: I currently can't test it myself, but be aware that the dev  console often behaves slightly different than actual Javascript execution, especially in edge cases like this or when entering something syntactically incorrect. There are also a few bug reports in browsers about that now an then, but they are understandingly treated as minor, because they are no standard use case.

Comment: @maja post your answer and I will take that. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Function is the built in prototype object that represents all functions. And Function can be used as a constructor also using new keyword

The entity "Function" itself is callable. Writing `Function()` is therefore a valid javascript statement.

This means that, when entering the string `Function` into the developer console, the browser will correctly print `ƒ Function() { [native code] }`.

The same happens if you enter, for example, `Math.random`. The browser sees that "random" is a function and prints `ƒ random() { [native code] }`.

If you enter the string `function` (lower case) instead, however, it cannot be interpreted by the browser, as it is only a keyword, not an actual object/entity. In chrome, the developer console doesn't let you execute that and waits for more input. The same happens if you try to enter `[`. When submitting `function;`, you will correctly get a Syntax Error.

Independently of that, be aware that the developer console often behaves slightly different than actual Javascript execution, especially in edge cases or when dealing with something syntactically incorrect. There are also few bug reports in browsers about that every now an then, but they are understandingly treated as minor as they don't fall into any standard use case.